# using CASE in a MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

How can I use `CASE` in a MySQL query? I'd like to perform something like this, where the value of one column on the table/view is used to create another column in the result set.

I don't know the correct syntax. How can this be done?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sex = 1 THEN 'Boy' ELSE THEN 'Girl' sex 
FROM user
```

Comment: Don't you mean update?

Comment: May I just add that the username and question are one in the same.

Answer (score 3):

Error syntax???

```
select 
CASE
    WHEN sex = 1
    THEN 'Boy'
    ELSE 'Girl'
end as sexName
FROM user
```

Comment: Should be end as sex, because OP is trying to "change data type".

Comment: It's not trying to change data type, it's rather projecting the value of one column into another.

Comment: He wants to use the same column name as currently exists for the column. He just want to change the contents.

Comment: The main question is not name of column but as he can retrieve that information. I add sexName (it's ok?) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN sex = 1
    THEN 'Boy'
    ELSE 'Girl'
END as sex
FROM user
```